# Generalised Pascal Triangle with two-periodic formula

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-proofs

Consider a generalisation of pascal's triangle of the following form
$$1 \\ 1 \ 1 \\ 1\ 2\\ 1\ 3\ 2\\ 1\ 4\ 5\\ 1\ 5\ 9\ 5$$
That is to say, for even-numbered rows the $n$-th term is found by adding the $(n-1)$-th and $n$-th terms of the previous row, and for odd-numbered rows, the rule is similar, except that no new term is added on the end at all. (For example, there is no $1$ on the end of the third row above.)

Is it possible to find a explicit expression for the entries of this triangle?

Motivation: This problem is related to the following problem of enumerative geometry: 'Let $n\geq 2$, given $(n-2)$-dimensional subspaces $H_1,\ldots, H_{2(n-2)}$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ how many lines are there, in general, intersecting all spaces?’

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008315 ?

Comment: See also the Wikipedia entry on [Catalan's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle). The table provided does include your triangle values, but with your rows appearing as rising diagonals. They moreover give a formula for the entries, suggesting a fairly definitive answer to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start with Pascal's triangle

```
1
1  1
1  2  1
1  3  3  1
1  4  6  4  1
1  5 10 10  5  1
1  6 15 20 15  6  1
```

precede and follow with $0$s

```
0  1  0
0  1  1  0
0  1  2  1  0
0  1  3  3  1  0
0  1  4  6  4  1  0
0  1  5 10 10  5  1  0
0  1  6 15 20 15  6  1  0
```

take differences between consecutive terms

```
1 -1
1  0 -1
1  1 -1 -1
1  2  0 -2 -1
1  3  2 -2 -3 -1 
1  4  5  0 -5 -4 -1
1  5  9  5 -5 -9 -5 -1
```

and finally drop the zero and negative values in the right-hand half

```
1 
1 
1  1 
1  2 
1  3  2  
1  4  5 
1  5  9  5
```

you get your triangle.

So, one possibility for a formula is $${n \choose m}-{n \choose m-1}$$ assuming you start counting rows and columns that way starting from $0$.  For example the $9$ here is ${6 \choose 2}-{6 \choose 1} = 15-6$

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: Do you have a proof in mind for why this method is correct? Although this solution is nicer I have accepted the one based on Catlan's triangle in the meantime.

Comment: @A.VanWerde once you have the formula it's easy to check that it satisfies the defining recurrence, after which you have your proof. (Although it's nice that you accepted my answer, I think this answer is more deserving of it!)

Comment: @YiFan Thank you for the clarification and other answer. As you suggest I have accepted this answer.

Comment: Ummm did you see this directly or did you reverse engineer it from the answer?

Comment: @user21820: he "read it off" of the operations he did on Pascal's triangle to get OP's triangle.

Comment: @nomen: My question is whether he knew he could get the asker's triangle from Pascal's triangle in this manner. It seems easier to reverse engineer the relationship once you know the answer, or if you guess it is possible.

Comment: @user21820: I recognised the numbers as coming from Catalan's Triangle which I know is based on the difference of two combinatorial coefficients

Comment: @Henry: Exactly what I thought. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 5):

As the comment by Semiclassical indicates, this is highly relevant to [Catalan's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle), defined by the recurrences $C(n+1,k)=C(n+1,k-1)+C(n,k)$ for $1<k<n+1$, $C(n+1,n+1)=C(n+1,n)$ for $n\geq1$, and the boundary conditions $C(n,0)=1$ for $n\geq0$ and $C(n,1)=n$ for $n\geq1$. There is an explicit formula for $C(n,k)$ given by $$C(n,k)=\frac{(n+k)!(n-k+1)}{k!(n+1)!}.$$
Now, if the $k$th entry in the $n$th row of your triangle is called $D(n,k)$, then 
it is easy to notice that $D(n,k)=C(n-k+1,k-1).$ (You can convince yourself by looking at how $D(n,k)$ are entries along the rising diagonal on the table of values provided in the Wikipedia page, or by verifying the defining recurrence is satisfied like so.) Consequently we have
$$\boxed{D(n,k)=C(n-k+1,k-1)=\frac{n!(n-2k+3)}{(k-1)!(n-k+2)!}}.$$